# while copy data to in json file in postgresql using query , record with single "\" is replaced with "\\"

Tags: database, postgresql

I have postgresql copy command like

```
\copy  (select row_to_json(xyz) from (select employeeJson from employee where empid='1006') xyz) to '/home/users/emp_create_cp_1006.json';
```

emplyeejson is a jsonb column and having record like

```
{
"empid": 1006,
"userId":"rirani",
"jobTitleName":"Developer",
"firstName":"Bala",
"lastName":"K",
"preferredFullName":"Bala K",
"employeeCode":"E1",
"region":"CA",
"phoneNumber":"408-1234567",
"emailAddress":"bala.k.k@gmail.com",
"address" : "10\" sarah apartment"
}
```

when the file is generated ,the address value become "10\" sarah apartment" ,which is a invalid json.

Comment: If `employeejson` is a jsonb column, then `row_to_json(xyz)` doesn't really make sense. You are nesting one JSON value into another. It seems you just want: `\copy  (select employeeJson from employee where empid=1006) to '/home/users/emp_create_cp_1006.json'`

Answer (score 1):

COPY TO does not produce verbatim text, it produces a text format in which backslash is a special character, with backlash in the contents being doubled, and whose main purpose is to be reloaded by a COPY FROM.

For your case, you may call `SELECT` with the `unaligned` format to suppress blank padding and `tuples_only` to suppress column names. It produces the exact value of the column without a layer of encoding or decoration.

In psql:

```
\pset format unaligned
\pset tuples_only
SELECT employeeJson from employee where empid=1006 \g /home/users/emp_create_cp_1006.json
```

Or from the shell:

```
$ psql -At [other options] -c 'SELECT employeeJson from employee where empid=1006' > /home/users/emp_create_cp_1006.json
```